# Proof of Komlós theorem .

Tags: measure-theory

I read an article, and they use a certain theorem, called Komlós theorem, which says:

> Let $(E,\mathcal {A}, \mu ) $ be a finite measure space and  $ (f_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1$ is a seqsequence  with : $$\sup_n \int_{E}{|f_n| d\mu} < \infty .$$Then there exist $ h _{\infty} \in  \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1 $ and a subsequence $ (g_k)_k $ of $(f_n)_n $  such that for every subsequence $ (h_m)_m $ of $(g_k)_k$ : $$ \frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}{h_j}\to   h _{\infty} \text{ a.s. }$$

I want to prove this theorem.  I know the proof of this theorem when $(E,\mathcal {A}, \mu ) $ is a probability space, you can find it in this site ([Understanding a proof of Komlós's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89263/understanding-a-proof-of-koml%c3%b3ss-theorem?r=SearchResults))

please an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This form of the theorem is an immediate corollary of the theorem for probability spaces.  Just note $(E,\mathcal{A}, \frac{\mu}{\mu(E)})$ is a probability space.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, but i didn't understand. if you can write the first step of the demo

Comment: Show/note $$\mathcal{L}^1(\mu) = \mathcal{L}^1\left(\frac{\mu}{\mu(E)}\right) \\ \sup_n \int_E |f_n|\,d\mu < \infty \iff \sup_n \int_E |f_n|\,\frac{d\mu}{\mu(E)} < \infty \\ \forall A \in \mathcal{A}, \mu(A) = 0 \iff \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(E)} = 0$$